# display content of selected item from listbox into textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0J7A.png)

I have a "simple" Question: How can i display the content of a selected item from a Listbox into a Textbox.
I tried it with

```
//string value1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();//textBox1.Text = value1;
```

but it will show me just the filename of the selcted item(i already find out why).

And i also tried somthing like:

```
//string value1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();//textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllLines(value1);
```

I know that i'll need the actual path of the selected file to "ReadAllLines"

And here is the Problem i have no clue how to get it, may someone can help me please.

Comment: How did you get the list of files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) in the first place?  Did you have the path at some point?  Store that path at class/form level if those files are all in the same place.

Comment: If they are not in the same place, then you should not put a plain string into your ListBox.  Instead, add an INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT to your ListBox.  You could add a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-3.1) and then tell the ListBox to display the `.Name` property by setting the ListBox's [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_DisplayMember) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file that you want to read is located relatively to the app path then use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` get the app path, and then `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine that path with your target relative path (or just the file name, if the file is located in the same folder as the app).

Answer (score 0):

My Solution with the help from Dialecticus:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string path1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(dataPath, value1);
            textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path1);

        }
```

*dataPath contains the path with the actual path

```
string dataPath = @"C: \Users\....;
```